# Validation to stop characters from being entered and up to 50 numeric characters

Tags: c, validation

I want to be able to stop the user entering any non-numeric characters into the .data part of the structure. They can also enter up to 50 numeric characters but no more. I have come up with this loop but it does not work. I'm new to C so I don't have a massive array of things to try.

```
do{
    puts("Enter up to 50 numerical characters");
    scanf("%50s", &records[*rCount].data);
    for(i = 0; i < records[*rCount].data; i++)
    {
        if(!isdigit(records[*rCount].data[i]))
        {
            valid = 0;
            getchar();
            puts("\nNot a valid input");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            valid = 1;
        }
    }

} while(valid!=1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Always test the result of `scanf()`

   ```
   if (scanf("%50s", &records[*rCount].data) != 1) {
     valid = 0;
     getchar();
     puts("\nNot a valid input");
     continue;
   }
   ```
2. Terminate your loop on `records[*rCount].data[i] == '\0'`

   ```
   for(i = 0; records[*rCount].data[i] != '\0'; i++)
   ```
3. Could use `if (scanf(" %50[0-9]", &records[*rCount].data) != 1)` and skip the for loop.